# How to increment input value by two in Java

Tags: java, input, output, increment

My program asks the individual to input 2 numbers (ie; 10 and 20). 
I would like the output to be:

Even numbers: 10 12 14 16 18 20

My code:

```
  System.out.println("Enter an integer:");
  int firstNum = keyboard.nextInt();

  System.out.println("Enter another integer larger than the first one:");
  int secondNum = keyboard.nextInt();

  System.out.println();

  int mod = firstNum % 2;

  while ((firstNum < secondNum) && mod == 0)
  {
      firstNum = firstNum + 2;
      System.out.print("Even numbers" +firstNum);
  }
```

Comment: If your values are 10 and 21 what do you expect to see? 10 12 14 16 18 20 21?

Comment: is the `print` statement giving the error?

Comment: I guess the internet already has the answer to this simple loop.

Comment: @Huiting Exactly like that except no 21 it should stop at 20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close to the result you are after, just need to rearrange the order of a couple of lines and add one `if` check.

I have made a complete example that runs as expected and allows for both odd and even numbers. You can replace your code with the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);      
    System.out.println("Enter an integer:");
    int firstNum = keyboard.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Enter another integer larger than the first one:");
    int secondNum = keyboard.nextInt();

    System.out.println();

    int mod = firstNum % 2;
    //If first number is odd, increase by one to make it even.
    if (mod != 0)
    {
        firstNum++;
    }

    System.out.print("Even Numbers: ");
    while (firstNum <= secondNum)
    {
        System.out.print(firstNum + " ");
        firstNum = firstNum + 2;
    }
    keyboard.close();
}
```